# How to break down a complex wave to basic waves

Tags: wave-equation

Let's say we have a wave that is made up of 3 sine waves all at different frequencies. It would be easy to figure out what those 3 original sine waves were by either basic observation, or trial and error. My question in regards to this though, is there a surefire way to retrieve the original building blocks (the 3 original sine waves) from the resulting wave?

Could the suggested method be used to find the building blocks (original sine waves) of a wave built up of n sine waves? Or is solution dependant on n. Ie. 0+1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about the Fourier Transform, and the discrete version the Fast Fourier Transform ([FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform))? That would be the preferred tool. The Python library `numpy` has FFT routines, C/C++ implementations are abundant too.

Comment: Thanks Brian! I believe this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. I spoke a little loosely: the discrete version of the Fourier Transform is.. the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT). The FFT is a particularly efficient implementation. As luck would have it, I recently came across a couple of very good articles on this topic which I think you'll get alot out of: [DFT article](http://sam-koblenski.blogspot.com/2015/10/everyday-dsp-for-programmers-discrete.html), and [FFT article](http://sam-koblenski.blogspot.com/2015/10/everyday-dsp-for-programmers-dft-in-use.html). Both are from a blog on various DSP topics; the 2 cited are later in the series.

Comment: "FFT is a[n] ... *implementation*": make that *algorithm*.